# Is it possible to add a row count to the filename of a report exported by a Report Server subscription?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2019, reportserver, ssrs-2019

I have a number of reports which are generated daily for my users by Report Server.

The subscription runs the reports and saves the files into a folder. I want to add a row count to the filename to make it more obvious which reports are which and to help my users prioritize their reports. Reports with a lot of rows are invariably more urgent to deal with in this context.

Is it possible to do this just using standard SSRS config, the Report Server web interface and Report Builder? Is there some setting in the export function I'm missing to add a rowcount variable to the filename?

I've searched this site, Microsoft Docs, Google etc and nobody seems to have covered this specific ask that I can see. Maybe I'm asking it wrong or maybe it just isn't supported? I have the latest Report Server update running on SQL Server 2019.

If I need to modify the Report Server stored procs to get it to do this, that also is an option but I'd prefer to use a supported method to do this if one exists.

Comment: One of the most requsted feature wtih a subscription is to dynamically change file names on a subscritpion.. and also the most ignored for some reason!

Comment: Do you have the Enterprise Edition? With Data Driven subscriptions, the filename can be set with a query (the data driven part) that *could* count the number of records and add it to the filename. You can emulate the Data Driven functionality but that takes a bit more work. FWIW, I don't care for the idea of a count in the filename. A datetime stamp doesn't help?

Comment: Standard edition sadly. How can I emulate the functionality in Standard? I don't mind how much work it is. The files already have date / time stamp but a rowcount is extremely useful for my users. I know this because I have already provided it to them. At the moment I am loading each file with Excel, using that to count the rows and renaming the files in VBA. Not ideal, slow as all hell and keeps crashing.